# Как сохранить динамические элементы на странице после перехода на другую страницу и обратно

Tags: jquery, append

Имеется список товаров магазина. При прокрутке страницы вниз ,динамически(append) добавляются другие товары магазина для просмотра.Пользователь переходит по товару который динамически подгрузился и возвращается обратно на страницу общего списка товаров.Как сделать так чтобы эти подгруженные товары остались на странице общего списка после перехода ?

Comment: А куда они денутся, если он кнопкой back браузера возвращается?

Comment: @KAGG Design Так я же эти товары добавляю динамически с помощью функции jQuery append ,на статической странице отображаются только первые 20 товаров .И после перехода по одному из подгруженных товаров и обратно ,отображаются только первые 20 товаров что у меня были статическими .

Comment: @KAGG Design То же самое они заново загружаются как и в моём случае .

Comment: Надо манипулировать историей браузера. Вот пример, он кривоватый, но суть из него извлечь можно: https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

Comment: Вот получше пример: http://digitarald.de/project/history-manager/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.